# Symfony2, composer, your PHP version (5.6.18) overriden by "config.platform.php" version (5.3.9) does not satisfy requirement

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, composer-php

I am trying to install doctrine to my project. I am getting the error about the wrong PHP version. What can be done to remove the real reason for this error? The way to overcome it is to use the option "`--ignore-platform-reqs`" as described https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require .

PHP version: PHP 5.6.18

```
PHP 5.6.18  (cli) (built: Feb  3 2016 17:20:21)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

The error:  c..>composer require doctrine/data-fixtures

```
Using version ^1.1 for doctrine/data-fixtures
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - doctrine/migrations v1.3.0 requires php ^5.5|^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6
.18) overriden by "config.platform.php" version (5.3.9) does not satisfy that re
quirement.
    - doctrine/migrations v1.2.2 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.1
8) overriden by "config.platform.php" version (5.3.9) does not satisfy that requ
irement.
    - doctrine/migrations v1.2.1 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.1
8) overriden by "config.platform.php" version (5.3.9) does not satisfy that requ
irement.
    - doctrine/migrations v1.2.0 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.1
8) overriden by "config.platform.php" version (5.3.9) does not satisfy that requ
irement.
    - doctrine/migrations v1.1.0 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.1
8) overriden by "config.platform.php" version (5.3.9) does not satisfy that requ
irement.
    - doctrine/migrations v1.0.0 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.1
8) overriden by "config.platform.php" version (5.3.9) does not satisfy that requ
irement.
    - Installation request for doctrine/migrations ~1.0 -> satisfiable by doctri
ne/migrations[v1.0.0, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.2.1, v1.2.2, v1.3.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

The content of composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures" : "~1.1",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install DoctrineMigrationsBundle via composer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160657/cannot-install-doctrinemigrationsbundle-via-composer)

Answer (score 120):

Somewhere in your `composer.json` you have

```
"config": {
   "preferred-install": "dist",
   "platform": {
       "php": "5.3.9"
   }
}
```

That block overrides your current PHP version as described in [composer doc](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform).

Answer (score 48):

In your composer.json, remove the following lines :

```
// ...
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.3.9"
    }
},
// ...
```

See [platform config in composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform).

Answer (score 2):

I just got the same problem (while doing "`composer install`").

But changing the config was not an option (because of office's repo conflicts), so I came up with below solution.

### Global config file <sup>(or Ignore PHP version)</sup>

It's recommended to only fake and/or configure
PHP version in "`~/.composer/config.json`" file (or Windows's "`%AppData%/Composer/config.json`" file), like:

```
{
    "config": {
        "platform":{
            "php":"5.5"
        }
    }
}
```

> Which composer may cache in `composer.lock` file, like:
>
> ```json
> {
>
>    ...
>
>    "platform-overrides": {
>        "php": "5.5"
>    }
> }
> ```

But we could also ignore it, like:

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: Please do not duplicate existing answers. Rather upvote one of those that you've found most helpful

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ @NicoHaase those answers are about `composer.json` file, this is about global `config.json` (with explanations like no other, please read carefully)

Answer (score 1):

I use doctrine migrations with Symfony 2.7

In my composer.json I have, I noticed you don't, you could try adding it

```
"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.0"
```

I manually installed migrations following Symfony2 docs, you can read it [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html).

This is my whole 2.7 Symfony composer:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.*@dev",
    "ircmaxell/password-compat": "^1.0",

    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1",
    "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.3@dev",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "~2.3@dev",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "~2.3@dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.0"

},
```

Comment: It's related to "config" section in composer.json

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with laravel 7.4, but I was using Laravel 8.2 before. So, I had to remove this lines from composer.json. Thanks chalasr. Now it's working fine again.

"config": {
"platform": {
"php": "8.2.0"
}
},