# FOSRestBundle & JMSSerializerBundle with symfony 2.7 and PHP 5.5.12

Tags: symfony

I'd like to add the 2 libraries **FOSRestBundle & JMSSerializerBundle** to my application built with **symfony 2.7** but i encountred this response

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle[dev-master].
    - friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle dev-master requires php ^5.5.9|~7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.12) overriden by "config.platform.php" version (5.3.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for jms/serializer-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by jms/serializer-bundle[dev-master].
    - jms/serializer-bundle dev-master requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.12) overriden by "config.platform.php" version (5.3.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Notice that **PHP version** is **5.5.12**

I think the problem is the version of this 2 libraries. If yes, What are the versions of FOSRestBundle & JMSSerializerBundle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dev-master` should never be used as version bound when requiring a package as dependency, except in some specific cases.

Go to https://packagist.org/ then search for the packages you are looking for and use their respective current stable version as version bound for your composer.json's requirement.

Also, in your composer.json, you have a `config` key containing a `platform.php` key with `5.3.9` as value. Remove or override this block according to your real PHP version. See [Symfony2, composer, your PHP version (5.6.18) overriden by "config.platform.php" version (5.3.9) does not satisfy requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538071/symfony2-composer-your-php-version-5-6-18-overriden-by-config-platform-php).

Of course, if the last stable version of one of them isn't compatible with your environment (PHP >= 5.5.9 for friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle), you need to look for an older version supporting your environment (all is available on packagist, and surely on the official documentation of these packages).