# Cannot install FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, bundle, fosuserbundle

I've a new Symfony project and want to install the FOSUserBundle, but it throws following error:

> Problem 1
>      - friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v2.0.1 requires php ^5.5.9 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.7) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.3.9) does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install DoctrineMigrationsBundle via composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160657/cannot-install-doctrinemigrationsbundle-via-composer)

Answer (score 4):

You have to change your php version on **composer.json**:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9", //or to 7.0.0
...........................
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try ignoring platform requirements:

`composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle:~2.0 --ignore-platform-reqs`